# What part of speech is "passes" in this context

Tags: parts-of-speech

> Harry and Ron had so far managed to **scrape passes** in this subject only by copying Hermione's notes before exams; she alone seemed able to resist the soporific power of Binns's voice.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix</sub>

I feel "**scrape passes**" is more like a compound word here, so it could be written as '*scrape-passes*'. What the part of speech is "passes" if we don't take it as a compound word?

Comment: Your surmise is totally off-base because of **to**.  If it had said "managed scrape passes" then it could work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably not a compound word. **"Scrape passes"** in this context most likely means "to barely pass [an exam or course]". It comes from the notion of "barely **scraping** by" (to do something with great difficulty, see [the definition [verb 4]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scraping)).

In this context, **passes** or **pass** if singular is just a simple way to say "a passing grade", which is used a noun.

Answer (score 2):

to scrape (something) means to manage to win or to get something

*The team scraped a narrow victory last year*.

*I just scraped a pass in the exam.*

to scrape - verb

a pass - noun

Answer (score 2):

According to the Cambridge Dictionary

**[manage](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/manage)**

> to succeed in doing or dealing with something, especially something difficult
>   **[ + to infinitive ]** *Did you manage to get any bread?*

In your sentence **manage** applies to an infinitive: **scrape**

[**scrape**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scrape)

> to succeed in getting or achieving **something**, but with difficulty or
>   **by a very small amount**

What's that **something** achieved by Harry and Ron? **Passes**

had managed to scrape passes - [verb] + to + infinitive + **object**.

@Tᴚoɯɐuo has pointed that this verb is intransitive but *is being used **transitively** here, which is unusual, at least to my AmE ear. This might be a BrE slang usage*

---

According to the Oxford Dictionary

[**pass**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pass) [noun]

> A success in an examination, test, or course.

The whole sentence means that they passed the exams but with **low** qualifications. Notice what I highlighted above: by a very small amount.

Comment: what does 'passes' mean exactly then?

Comment: @dan I've updated my answer.

Comment: The verb **scrape** is being used transitively here, which is unusual, at least to my AmE ear.  I've always heard it as an intransitive verb, **to scrape by**, which means to barely manage.  The example you cited in the Oxford dictionary is also not taking a direct object. This might be a BrE slang usage.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Good point. You're right, the verb "scrape" is marked as intransitive in the Cambridge Dictionary but in OP's text "pass" is the object